# Why does flutter throw invalid argument(s) when grabbing children based on index?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Ok, so I'm currently using a PageBuilder and what I'm doing works, but I don't really like the sliding physics. I'd rather just have them tap the bottomappbar to navigate.

**WORKING CODE**:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  PageController controller = PageController();

  List<GButton> tabs = new List();

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Settings(),
    ListFamily(),
    CameraScreen(),
    SplashAccount(),
    Questions()
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 5);
    double gap = 10;

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.settings,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Settings',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.wc,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Relations',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.camera_alt,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Camera',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.video_library,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Videos',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.question_answer,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Questions',
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: PageView.builder(
          onPageChanged: (page) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = page;
            });
          },
          controller: controller,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: _children[position]),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                          bottomRight: Radius.zero),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            spreadRadius: -10,
                            blurRadius: 60,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.20),
                            offset: Offset(0, 15))
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    child: GNav(
                        tabs: tabs,
                        selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                        onTabChange: (index) {
                          print(index);
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: tabs.length, // Can be null
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Invalid argument(s) code**:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  PageController controller = PageController();

  List<GButton> tabs = new List();

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Settings(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container()
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 5);
    double gap = 10;

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.settings,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Settings',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.wc,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Relations',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.camera_alt,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Camera',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.video_library,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Videos',
    ));

    tabs.add(GButton(
      gap: gap,
      iconActiveColor: maincolor,
      iconColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: maincolor,
      iconSize: 24,
      padding: padding,
      icon: Icons.question_answer,
      // textStyle: t.textStyle,
      text: 'Questions',
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
// _children[selectedIndex] will cause the Invalid Argument(s) error here.
                Expanded(child: _children[selectedIndex]),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                          bottomRight: Radius.zero),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            spreadRadius: -10,
                            blurRadius: 60,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.20),
                            offset: Offset(0, 15))
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                    child: GNav(
                        tabs: tabs,
                        selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                        onTabChange: (index) {
                          print(index);
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

I'm currently only using Flutter's Material library and this plugin: https://github.com/sooxt98/google_nav_bar

Also, I've tried this with other bottom navigation bars as well, I'm just stumped as to why this happens

The children in the working code are my other pages.
The settings page code is below:

```dart
class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<Settings> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Logo + Container
              Container(
                color: thirdcolor,
                child: Center(
                  child: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  "assets/mvvdesign/Solid/White/horizontal/logo.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Container for Questions bar

              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "SETTINGS",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: fontsize,
                                fontFamily: fontfamily,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Divider(
                              height: 5.0,
                              thickness: 3.0,
                              endIndent: 100.0,
                              indent: 100.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Hey, ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Alyssa Thurman",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 24.0,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 360.0,
                        height: 56.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "Update Account Information",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: maincolor),
                        )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 360.0,
                        height: 56.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "Terms and Conditions",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: maincolor),
                        )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 360.0,
                        height: 56.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "Privacy Policy",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: maincolor),
                        )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 360.0,
                        height: 56.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          "Manage Membership",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: maincolor),
                        )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 360.0,
                        height: 56.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            color: Colors.red),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 40.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await OneSignal.shared.logoutEmail();
                            SharedPreferences prefs =
                                await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                            prefs.remove('accesstoken');
                            prefs.remove('refreshtoken');
                            prefs.remove('email');
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First()),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            "LOGOUT",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: thirdcolor,
    );
  }
}
```

Error log: https://pastebin.com/raw/Regkgcqk

Comment: you should point out where the problem lies, and its the stackTrace which tells whats the actual problem is, post it

Comment: added the error log

Comment: Some where you have to pass the length of the List I'm unable to pin point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: I figured out why it wasn't working (fairly sure). I have a function that grabs a saved index value from persistent storage and sets selectedIndex to this value upon initialization of the state.

However, when the saved index is grabbed, it returns a null (because it has not been set yet) value. Therefore it passes this null value to selectedIndex and subsequently the builder as well; leading to an invalid argument(s) error because the index cannot be null.

The function in question is not included in the above incorrect code, so both code snippets should work. The reason it wasn't working for me is likely because the index was cached and it was considering the index to be null every time the state was reloaded.

**Alternative solution**:

Use a pageview builder and set the properties to your preferences.

My preference:
Inside of PageView.builder()

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```